# Looping through nested NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, recursion, plist

I know there is a somewhat simple solution here, I can't quite wrap my head around it though.
I have a user generated .plist file that can have a (reasonable) infinite amount of nested trees in it. What I'm wanting to do is create a folder structure based on how the plist is nested.

[image: .plist example]

Since I do not know how deep the main dictionary goes I cant figure out how to loop through it and tell it to create a directory then dive into that and create directories within it.

I know how to create folders its iterating through the entire list is what is throwing me off. I'm pretty sure I need a separate recursive method just am not sure where to begin. Key "Children" and "Name" are what I'm using to create the list. Any help would be great.

Comment: recursion is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with defining a path to the directory where you want to create the directory structure. Then call the function to build the directory structure.

```
NSString *pathToDirectory = @"./";
[self buildDirectoriesAtPath: pathToDirectory fromDictionary: dictionary];
```

The function **`-buildDirectoriesAtPath:fromDictionary:`** is recursive and would look something like this:

```
- (void) buildDirectoriesAtPath: (NSString *) filepath fromDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {

    for (NSString *key in dictionary.allKeys) {

        if ([key isEqualToString: @"Children"]) {

            NSArray *children = [dictionary objectForKey: key];
            for (id object in children) {

                if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
                    NSDictionary *directoryInfo = (NSDictionary *) object;
                    NSString *directoryName = [directoryInfo objectForKey: @"Name"];
                    NSString *directoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", filepath, directoryName];

                    //  Create directory
                    NSLog(@"Creating directory: %@", directoryPath);

                    //  Create subdirectories
                    NSArray *subdirectories = [directoryInfo objectForKey: @"Children"];
                    for (id directory in subdirectories) {

                        if ([directory isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
                            NSString *subdirectoryName = (NSString *) directory;
                            NSString *subdirectoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", directoryPath, subdirectoryName];

                            //  Create directory
                            NSLog(@"Creating directory: %@", subdirectoryPath);
                        }
                        else if ([directory isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
                            NSDictionary *subdirectory = (NSDictionary *) directory;
                            NSString *subdirectoryName = [subdirectory objectForKey: @"Name"];
                            NSString *subdirectoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@/", directoryPath, subdirectoryName];

                            [self buildDirectoriesAtPath: subdirectoryPath fromDictionary: (NSDictionary *) directory];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
                    NSString *directoryName = (NSString *) object;
                    NSString *directoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", filepath, directoryName];

                    //  Create directory
                    NSLog(@"Creating directory: %@", directoryPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there's anything you'd like clarified in this, don't hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: That's perfect, just what I was after. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

May be this function will help you,

```
void recursiveCall (NSDictionary *dictionary) {
    NSArray *_keys = [dictionary allKeys];
    for (NSString *_key in _keys) {
        id obj = [dictionary valueForKey:_key];
        NSLog(@"Create folder of %@",_key);
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for (id _obj in obj) {
                if ([_obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                    recursiveCall(_obj);
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Create folder of %@",_obj);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```